# Django Multiple Foreign Keys to none target or source model in intermediate model

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to use multiple foreign keys within an intermediate model. From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

> Your intermediate model must contain one - and only one - foreign key to the source model (this would be Group in our example), or you must explicitly specify the foreign keys Django should use for the relationship using ManyToManyField.through_fields. If you have more than one foreign key and through_fields is not specified, a validation error will be raised. A similar restriction applies to the foreign key to the target model (this would be Person in our example).

To me this implies that I should be able to use multiple references to a none target or source model assuming I have specified foreign keys it isn't the source or target. However with the sample below I still get the following error:

> "IntermediaryModel' has more than one ForeignKey to 'app.Model3'

I've stripped back the code below to only include the relationships between the four models I'm seeing this issue with. Where have I gone wrong with the model relationships?

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...


class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ManyToManyField(Model1,
                                      through='Model4',
                                      through_fields=('field1', 'field2'))


class Model3(models.Model):
    field1= models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)


class Model4(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
    field2= models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    field3= models.ForeignKey(Model3, null=True)
    field4 = models.ForeignKey(Model3, null=True)
```

Using Python 2.7, Django v1.11

Comment: Aren't fields `field3` and `field4` in `Model4` completely redundant?

Comment: Possibly, I don't have much experience with ORM. My reason for doing this is to store specific entries which will be retrieved frequently rather than having to retrieve and filter each time. My use case is that model 3 represents a time which is linked to both model 1 and 2. In fields 3 and 4 I want to store references to a personal best time and first time and wanted to avoid retrieving all linked times and calculating which is which every time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you add a field in `Model3` that stores personal best time and then have just one field in `Model4` access `Model3` as a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Thanks, yes I think that would work for me. I could go further and store both references in model 3 to avoid needing an intermediary table entirely I suppose but at first glance I thought this approach would be neater. From the documentation it seems like I should be able to do similar to what I have attempted but must have missed something somewhere.

Comment: I guess it's also worth pointing out that I have more than 4 fields in that model in my implementation which lots of additional info (think things like average time etc) but I've removed them to try and keep things simple. Ideally I'd keep all of this related information in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looked like I had an issue with how my intermediary model was configured. However it turns out that I actually had an issue with how my Django inlines were specified (which weren't in the above code as I didn't realise it was relevant):

```
class Model3Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model3
    extra = 1

class Model3(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (Model4,)
```

The inline tries to automatically assign to the relevant field but doesn't know which foreign key reference to pick, throwing the error.

In my case this was a mistake and I wanted to remove this reference as it wasn't necessary for what I wanted to do. A brief search on the topic highlighted the use of [fk_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name) to specify a specific field when multiple foreign keys are in used in a single model.